# $http.get success event after loading data in html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to initialize some jquery plugin after data is loaded in dom from $http.get request.
See below code:

```
//this is get request code. I'm getting json data properly.
$http.get('reordering.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.words = data.data;
        alert($("#sortable").html())
        $("#sortable").sortable();
});
```

From below code `<li>` is generating properly but I'm not able to initialize jquery plugin because in `alert()` it is not showing data loaded from json. `setTimeout()` will work but I want to know which is proper way to do this.

```
<ul id="sortable" class="dragContainer">
   <li class="dragHolder" ng-repeat="word in words">
       <div class="drag">{{word.value}}</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/333777). You are doing some things wrong at the moment:

1. Do not manipulate DOM in controllers.
2. Add behaviour with directives.

Using these two advices, you can solve the problem by directive that will activate jQuery UI sortable on `.dragContainer`. [Here's an implementation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) of such directive. The code will look similar to this:

```
<ul class="dragContainer" ng-model="words" ui-sortable>
   <li class="dragHolder" ng-repeat="word in words">
       <div class="drag">{{word}}</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

```
angular
.module("app", ["ui.sortable"])
.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.words = ["word one", "word two", "word three", "word four"];
  }, 1500);  
})
```

I have replaced `$http` with `$timeout` to imitate async request.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/toguwusibona/3/edit).